# Trying to substring a text field using Charindex

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I extract the number after Goal Rate of Infusion:

```
Substring(SummaryLine, CHARINDEX('n:',summaryline) , 
        LEN(SummaryLine) - CHARINDEX('n:',summaryline)-1) AS NewSumLine  

  , Initial Rate:  40, Goal Rate of Infusion:  55, to goal rate in 8 hours
    , Initial Rate:  40, Goal Rate of Infusion:  60, to goal rate in 8 hours
    , Initial Rate:  30, Goal Rate of Infusion:  30, to goal rate in 8 hours
    , Initial Rate:  30, Goal Rate of Infusion:  30, to goal rate in 8 hours, Dilution:  half strength
    , Initial Rate:  30, Goal Rate of Infusion:  40, to goal rate in 8 hours
    , Initial Rate:  30, Goal Rate of Infusion:  50, 20 ml every 4 hours to goal rate
    , Initial Rate:  50, Goal Rate of Infusion:  50, to goal rate in 8 hours
```

Answer (score 0):

Such extractions are a pain in SQL Server.  I'm inclined to use a series of `outer apply`s for this purpose.  However, in your case, the positions all appear to be fixed, so I would suggest:

```
select substring(summaryline, 43, 2)
```

If the example data is not quote accurate, then if requires more work:

```
select t2.val
from t outer apply
     (select stuff(t.summaryline, 1, charindex('n:  ', t.summaryline) + 4) as l1
     ) t1 outer apply
     (select left(t1.l1, charindex(',', t1.l1) - 1) as val
     ) t2;
```

You might need some additional conditional logic, if `summaryline` might not contain the value.  In addition, this assumes that `n:` is sufficient for identifying the location in the string.